# How to add user registration and signup in WordPress and create members only page?

Tags: user-registration, membership, signup

I'm trying to add a user login system in my WordPress as like regular PHP sites. 
when a user logged in then , i wanna show the specific page content otherwise no. Is there any process to add nice registration and login system in WordPress and no back end access also ?

thanks

Comment: No code, no research, no effort on your behalf. This is a do my work for me for free question with no real respect for the WordPress Development Community and should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block users from WordPress back office, you may use [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-block-admin/) plugin. To show specific page content after login, you need to hook through the redirection filter after login and redirect them to that page directly. If you don't want to write code for it, there is a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect) also.

Comment: Links to plugins DO NOT help WordPress Developers and are NOT considered an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually recommend plugins, but for what you need this one will work perfect and it's by a respected developer:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

As for the login screen, if you don't like the current WordPress log-in screen there are plugins for customizing it:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-login/

Comment: Links to plugins DO NOT help WordPress Developers and are NOT considered an answer. Links to posts are also not permanent.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with two plugins:
Profile Builder: http://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/ 
It adds front end login, registration and edit profile pages.

Members: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/ 
You can restrict pages or posts to logged in users only.

Comment: Links to plugins DO NOT help WordPress Developers and are NOT considered an answer.